# Array length doesn't match index

Tags: javascript

```js
var index = 0;
var length = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"].length;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
 if (index < length) {
  console.log(index);
  console.log(length);
  index++;
 } else {
       clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000);
```

How do i fix that? So it will clear interval on 5:5 not 4:5

Comment: Array's always start with 0 if not specified otherwise.

Comment: start index from 1.

Comment: `console.log(index + 1);` maths rock!

Comment: Index starts at `0`, length is amount so it's greater by 1 from last index

Comment: Anuga is right. if you want to display 1,2,3,4,5 do `console.log(index + 1);`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The array index starts at 0 and the length is just a count of the total items.. They have the same size but the first is always -1

Comment: I want to clear interval if index is = legth. or if index is < length. But it gives false output, because array starts from 0 and i add +1 to index so it doesn't match at the end.

Comment: Be careful with that because normally an array index would get outbounds when arrive to array length.. Because as I said array index starts at 0 and length counts the items starting at 1

Answer (score 0):

You could check the incremented `index` after an output.

If `index` is greater or equal to `length` clear the interval.

```js
var index = 0,
    length = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"].length,
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        console.log(index, length);
        if (++index >= length) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

hmmm

```js
var index = 0;
var length = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"].length;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
 if (index < length) {
                ++index;
  console.log(index);
  console.log(length);
 } else {
       clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: There isn't anything to explain since I just moved the index ++  and placed it before the console.log

Comment: @Osakr well you changed from `index++` to `++index` wondering what the reason for that is since it wouldn't matter here.

Comment: In this case it won't matter to put index++ or ++index I did it only for faster writing

Answer (score 0):

lenght give the quantitity. This is 5, but index starts with zero.

```js
var index = 0;
var length = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"].length;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
 if (index < length) {
  console.log(index + 1);
  console.log(length);
  index++;
 } else {
       clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is all you need

```js
var index = 0;
var length = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"].length;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
 if (index <= length) {
  console.log(index);
  console.log(length);
  index++;
 } else {
       clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000);
```